# How to find files containing string?

Tags: files, grep, find

I tried:

```
grep "$1-2400000" /media/linux/DATADISK/flashka/
```

It is running and doing nothing for a long time. Is there another way? It is not necessary to do that with the terminal.

Comment: Do you want to grep a literal `$1` or is this supposed to be a variable to be expanded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `-r` to match "all files" and should probably use single-quotes:

```bash
grep -r -l -F '$1-2400000' /media/linux/DATADISK/flashka/
```

With `-l`, grep will only show you filenames, not the match in the file.
`-F` greps for a fixed string, instead of a regex.

If your filenames contain spaces or other special characters, you may want to make use of `find` instead:

```bash
find /media/linux/DATADISK/flashka/ -type f -exec grep -l -F '$1-2400000' {} \;
```